# how to stop scrolling gallery?

Tags: android, scroll, gallery

I've got a gallery (images) in a `RelativeLayout` and if the users click on it, three `Buttons` and a `TextView` appears. I made it with the visible-property, that means the three `Buttons` and the `TextView` are declared as invisible in the xml-file and later the `onClick()` of the `Gallery` makes it visible with `setVisibility(0)`.That works fine, but I want the `Gallery` to stop scrolling during the `Buttons` and the `TextView` are in front.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't think `[stop]` is a very descriptive tag.

Comment: Hi Josh,

thanks for your answer. Maybe there is a way with onFling() ? but what mean the parameters 'MotionEvent` and 'velocityX' ?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to enable/disable scrolling of the Gallery, you could use class like this:

```
public class ExtendedGallery extends Gallery {

  private boolean stuck = false;

  public ExtendedGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public ExtendedGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public ExtendedGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return stuck || super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
      return stuck || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
  }

  public void setScrollingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    stuck = !enabled;
  }

}
```

According to the Gallery source code, there are two event types that start the scrolling: screen touch and the key, pressed on D-pad. So you could intercept these events if you want to disable scrolling. Then use something like this in your layout:

```
<your.package.name.ExtendedGallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Then you can enable/disable scrolling of that gallery at any time:

```
ExtendedGallery mGallery = (ExtendedGallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
mGallery.setScrollingEnabled(false); // disable scrolling
```

Comment: This also disables the itemClickListener for the items inside the Gallery's adapter.