# How to disable scrolling in Gallery

Tags: android, android-layout, gallery, alignment

I'm try to implement disable Gallery scrolling when pictures in gallery is less than 5 pictures.If I have more than 6 pics the scrolling will enable scrolling in Gallery!
but I have no idea how to implement it. I have already reference ["Gallery default item selected is in center"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404590/gallery-default-item-selected-is-in-center), to adjust first picture to the left,

after adjust the first picture, I reference ["how to stop scrolling gallery?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619197/how-to-stop-scrolling-gallery) , but it doesn't work! and ["Android Custom gallery to disable scrolling.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409402/android-custom-gallery-to-disable-scrolling) don't have any solution..
Any one have idea? how to disable scrolling the picture in Gallery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I am giving you one solution whatever I am getting from your question In place of gallery You can make view like gallery by using Horizontal scroll view, add linearLayout in that and add image view dynamically if images is coming dynamically to linearLayout so it will resolved scrolling issue and left align problem as well.

Comment: thanks, I can use HorizontalScrollView and linearLayout to solve the scrolling problem, but another problem is how to set the click event? In Gallery, I can got the position and set some intent when I click the picture, but when i using HorizontalScrollView, i don't know hot to get the position and index.plz help thanks!

Comment: Now you can set INDEX as a ImageView tag from image forloop and set click listner of all imageview and after click that image you will get v.getTag from clicklistner and compare it. that will resolve your problem if so accept the answer.

Comment: +1 for nice suggestion and i have also implement this in my project. As my project requirement Now i have one issue that i am not able to scroll disable horizontalscroll.